# How do I use AutoMapper with foreign key in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I have 3 classes that are a realization of table in SQL:

```
public partial class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Role1 { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<RolesAction> RolesActions { get; } = new List<RolesAction>();
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; } = new List<UserRole>();
}

public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; } = new List<UserRole>();
}

public partial class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual User User { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

and DTO classes:

```
public partial class RoleDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Role1 { get; set; } = null!;
}

public partial class UserDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}

public partial class UserRoleDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

I want to convert between classes with Role class and User class I managed. This is what I did:

```
internal class UserAndUserDTO : Profile
{
    public UserAndUserDTO()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDTO>()
           .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

And it works great but with the link `UserRole` and `UserRoleDTO` it doesnt work.

I am writing this:

```
internal class UserRoleAndUserRoleDTO : Profile
{
    public UserRoleAndUserRoleDTO()
    {
        CreateMap<UserRole, UserRoleDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.User,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.Name))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Role,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Role.Role1))
            .ReverseMap();  
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image: this is the img of the result]

What can I change in my code that it will make it work?

Comment: To load related entities, you need to [include related entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) on EF query.

Comment: Are you using `ProjectTo<UserDTO>()`?  ReverseMap won't work with references to go from a DTO back to entities. If you add or remove relationships you will want to eager load all existing relationships, determine what IDs have been added or removed, then for additions load those new relations and add associations, and remove existing relationships that are no longer referenced. If Automapper can do anything it would be to create a new Role entity instance which would result in duplicate data or errors for existing rows/tracked entities.